# Global authorized_keys associated with a user?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, user-management

Is it possible to have a global authorized_keys file that associates each user to their own public key?

For example, I would like to create multiple user accounts by their Github user name and public key. Instead of iterating through each user & key, can I dump them to a single global authorized_keys file? e.g. githubusername: publickey

Comment: You could use `AuthorizedKeysCommand` to run a script something like `grep ^"$1" globalfile | cut -f2-` (tweak as desired)

Answer (score 0):

Not as part of stock OpenSSH, no.  Many years ago I patched OpenSSH to do lookups of keys into MySQL, and it wasn't particularly difficult, so you could give that a go if you're dead set on going down that path.

Answer (score 0):

now we could use global keys in configs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836829/global-ssh-key-on-server

> [...] AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys
> [...]

Comment: That associates ALL users with a key (or several), not each user with their own key as requested. (And it's not new, it's been there for decades.)